# Error 404 when using the bloomberg addin for excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to create a notification system for Excel VBA, however I've hit a brick wall that I can't seem to be able to solve. I keep getting *Error 404 - Object Required* for the code I created. Hope you all can help.

```
Public price_col As Range
Public vol_col As Range

Public Sub setVars()
    Set price_col = Range("E2:E90")
    Set vol_col = Range("J2:J90")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    checkPrice price_col
    checkVol vol_col
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    setVars

    If Not Intersect(target, price_col) Is Nothing Then
        checkPrice target
    End If

    If Not Intersect(target, vol_col) Is Nothing Then
        checkVol target
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub checkPrice(target As Range)

  **For Each cell In target**

    Dim row As Long
    row = Range(cell.Address).row

    If cell.Value > 0.025 Then
        If ThisWorkbook.getPriceState(row) <> 1 Then
            MsgBox "Price " & Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(cell.Value * 100 / 1, 0) * 1 & "% rise: " & Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -2).Value
            ThisWorkbook.setPriceState row, 1
        End If
    ElseIf cell.Value < -0.025 Then
        If ThisWorkbook.getPriceState(row) <> -1 Then
            MsgBox "Price " & Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(cell.Value * 100 / 1, 0) * 1 & "% fall: " & Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -7).Value
            ThisWorkbook.setPriceState row, -1
        End If
    ElseIf cell.Value <> "" Then
        If ThisWorkbook.getPriceState(row) <> 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.setPriceState row, 0
        End If
    End If
  Next cell
End Sub

Public Sub checkVol(vol_col As Range)
For Each cell In vol_col
    Dim row As Long
    row = Range(cell.Address).row

    If cell.Value >= 2.5 Then
        If ThisWorkbook.getVolState(row) <> 3 Then
            MsgBox "Volume Change above 250%" & Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -7).Value
            ThisWorkbook.setVolState row, 3
        End If
    ElseIf cell.Value >= 2 Then
        If ThisWorkbook.getVolState(row) <> 2 Then
            MsgBox "Volume Change above 200%" & Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -7).Value
            ThisWorkbook.setVolState row, 2
        End If
    ElseIf cell.Value >= 1.5 Then
        If ThisWorkbook.getVolState(row) <> 1 Then
            MsgBox "Volume Change above 150%" & Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -7).Value
            ThisWorkbook.setVolState row, 1
        End If
    ElseIf cell.Value <> "" Then
        If ThisWorkbook.getVolState(row) <> 0 Then
            ThisWorkbook.setVolState row, 0
        End If
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

I got the error on the code "for each cell in target"; which was bolded. Thanks for helping!

Comment: None of the 700+ existing questions about this exact error helped?

Comment: (a) Is the error occurring during a call from the `Calculate` event or from the `Change` event?  (b) What do `getPriceState`, `setPriceState`, `getVolState` and `setVolState` do? (Do any of them update the sheet, or call `checkPrice`?)

Comment: @YowE3K it happened from the change event; since the excel is connected to the Bloomberg API, I am able to extract tick by tick data. Hence the pricestate and volstate

Comment: Once `MsgBox()` is fired, you are stuck there until someonce click it to continue the loop... is that really desired?

Answer (score 0):

If your calculate event fires, and the variables aren't set, then you'll get the error. At the very least, you should add a call to `setVars` at the start of `Worksheet_Calculate`

Comment: Thanks! I've added setVars right below Worksheet_Calculate, however the problem still exists.